# Add reference to netNamedPipeBinding WCF in .net core

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asp.net-core, ipc

Well, this will be a bit long :)

I have a project using asp.net core 1.1.2, using .net framework. I want to do a inter process communication (IPC) with an windows service. This windows service has a self-hosted WCF service. I was thinking about using `netNamedPipeBinding`, because the communication is on the same machine only.

I am trying to add reference to my named pine in my asp.net core project. I right click on "Dependencies" -> "Add connected service" -> "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider - Preview". Then i insert my named pipe address: "net.pipe://localhost/mynamedpipe/". Then i click on "Go". Then I get this error message:

> An error occurred while attempting to find services at
>   'net.pipe://localhost/mynamedpipe/'. The service Uri is not valid:
>   'net.pipe://localhost/mynamedpipe/'

I have created a console application and, using the old wizard ("Add Services Reference"), I successfully configured it. And it works as expected.

So my question is, how can I add reference in my .net core project to my `netNamedPipeBinding` WCF?

My second question is, based on my previous description, is this the best approach for IPC or is better use other binding?

Thanks a lot

Comment: ASP.NET Web API or SignalR is more modern a way to do IPC, while WCF was the past.

Comment: WCF client for .NET Core is open source at GitHub, https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues so you might simply open a new issue there to consult Microsoft.

Comment: @Lex Li, actually i make it work using basicHttpBinding. Any way, i will open a new issue in Github. Thanks a lot.